# Unable to record elements in Testsigma

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, artificial-intelligence

I have been unable to record element in Testsigma. I have already installed chrome extension for it.

Once recording started I clicked on different elements but it did not save the respective locator.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r309b.png)

I have download zip from the github link and downloaded all the folders TestsigmaAgent and TestsigmaServer. And also started start_nginx.bat.